# Convert MPEG-H 3d back to MPEG-H master (MPF) or ADM BWF file

Tags: audio, mix, dolby

I'm recently experimenting with 360 reality audio format. It seems like currently there are only tools to encode mpeg-h 3d mp4 files from master files, and no easy way to decode. Is it technically possible to convert encoded mpeg-h 3d mp4 files back to MPF or ADM BWF masters? If so, which tool(s) can do that?